# How common is 'rider' in the sense '[a]n amendment or addition to an entertainer's performance contract'?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

I came across a usage of the common word **rider** on a TV cookery show that I'd never met before. On checking, I found just two online dictionaries with the very specific definition

> *rider* [noun] [UK data] ...
>
> [c] a statement added to the contract of a performer saying what they
> would like to have provided in their dressing room:
>
> - *He requested only Pepsi and a few slices of pizza on his rider for a personal appearance.*
> - *The singer's 25-page rider included "non smelly" cheese, six kinds of water, and five sofas.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rider)]

> *rider* ...
>
> [2.2] An amendment or addition to an entertainer's performance
> contract, often covering a performer's equipment or food, drinks, and
> general comfort requirements. [from 20th c.]

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rider)]

Given that M-W, Collins, OALD, Longman, AHD and Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary don't mention the specific provision of extras (nibbles, drinks ...) for artistes (though the general 'extra stipulation' sense is of course well known), I'd like to ask how common this usage is, in the States and the UK.

Comment: Wiktionary has a more articulated definition of rider in that respect: An addition, supplements:
1) (politics) A supplementary clause added to a document after drafting, especially to a bill under the consideration of a legislature. [from 17th c.]
2) An amendment or addition to an entertainer's performance contract, often covering a performer's equipment or food, drinks, and general comfort requirements. [from 20th c.]
3) An additional matter or question arising in corollary; a qualification. [from 19th c.] 
4) A supplementary question, now especially in mathematics. [from 19th c.]

Comment: I specify the subsense I find unusual.

Comment: Well, any type of contract can have a rider.

Comment: Some of the more exotic riders... https://www.marieclaire.com/celebrity/g15872900/absurd-celebrity-riders/

Comment: Seems like a figurative use of **extra** or **add-on**.

Comment: There are also riders for insurance policies. As an example, if I built a swimming pool on my property, my standard homeowner’s policy might provide no protection in case someone should have an accident in it and sue me. So to obtain coverage for this new liability, my insurance company might sell a rider for my policy.

Comment: It's possibly more common in the UK. But not unknown elsewhere, certainly in the fields of entertainment and law. Asking how common a usage is is not a thing you can put a single numerical value to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *OED* lists this specific use of *rider* starting at 1975. It’s a rider to a performance agreement—covering performer requirements of all kinds (not just comestibles):

> ***rider*** *noun*
> **III.** An addition or supplement.
> **III.17.c.** *spec.* A supplementary clause in a performer’s contract specifying particular requirements for accommodation, food, drink,
> etc. Also (chiefly *British*)*: the items so specified or provided;
> (hence) an additional fee paid in kind to a performer, usually in the
> form of food and drink.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Surely you’ve heard of Van Halen’s legendary [M&M’s-no-brown-ones rider line item](https://www.thesmokinggun.com/file/van-halens-legendary-mms-rider?page=8)?

> Back in the 1980s, the rock band Van Halen had a long list of demands
> in its contract rider—endless picky notes about the stage setup, the
> lighting and all kinds of technical details, along with various food
> mandates. The wildest request by far was a line item requesting a bowl
> of M&M’s, with “absolutely no brown ones.”
>  <sub>Source:
> [Smithsonian Magazine, Arts & Culture, July 21,
> 2023](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/why-did-van-halen-demand-concert-venues-remove-brown-mms-from-the-menu-180982570/)</sub>

If the *OED*’s blessing is not sufficient, you can search `“performance agreement rider”` and such to find many more examples that indicate its commonness.

---

<sub>* In a metonymic flight of fancy, those Brits are eating the rider:</sub>

> <sub>**2002**   So why don’t we go off to their dressing room and
> eat their rider like you said?</sub>

Comment: Thanks. The example I came across had something like "Do you get riders, Aled? I always get Leedsie Bars. I don't like Leedsie Bars" showing that riders have flown even further, to include items provided without having been requested by the performer.

Comment: Ah, yes — that sounds like the “chiefly *British*” usage: the stuff provided.